# couchbase document read date/time

Tags: couchbase, spring-data-couchbase

i want to implement a feature that shows when a couchbase document is last read.

Is this saved by default in meta data of couchbase or i need to update the document with a field on every read so it can be retrieved later on .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing like that in the metadata, you'd have to update the document yourself.

> **Side note**: For writes/updates, you could have made use of the auditing annotation feature of Spring Data (supported by Spring Data Couchbase since SDC 2.1.1) but not for reads.

Also note that performance will suffer as you'd have to effectively perform a write for each read. And there's also the potential consistency side-effects: what if there's already a write of the same document happening in parallel?

To implement this, if you can wait for Couchbase Server 4.5, you should maybe consider using the sub-document API. (see [this blog](http://blog.couchbase.com/2016/february/subdocument-couchbase-java-sdk)).